# JS function gradually becomes slower

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js function that runs onclick on one of my pages, it does some text searching using regex on a global array of objects.

Now everytime I run this function it starts becoming slower and slower - first time is lightning fast, second time it takes a second, and eventually it freezes firefox.

here is a simplifed version of my code -

```js
var search = function(words){
 
 
 var results = [];
 var words = words.toLowerCase();
 var searchArr = words.split(' '); 
 var regexptemplate = '^';
 $.each(searchArr,function(){
  regexptemplate += "(?=.*\\b" + this + ")";
 });
 regexptemplate += ".+";
 var regex = new RegExp(regexptemplate);
  
 for(var index = 0; index < searchObj.length; index++){// check every model sentence
  var curObj = searchObj[index];
  var i;
  // find the actual sentence
  for(i = 1; ((i+1) < 11) && (curObj['level' + (i+1)] != null); i++); 
  
  // get sentence in english and german
  var text = curObj['level' + i];
  var engText = curObj['eng' + i];
  if(engText == null){// make sure not to crash the search just because a sentence wasn't formatted right'
   engText = "";
  }
  
  if ((regex.test(text.toLowerCase()) || regex.test(engText.toLowerCase())) && text.indexOf('{SENTENCE}')!= 0){// check if the word exists in the german or english
   // format sentence to not be too long
   var displayText = text;
   var displayEngText = engText;
   $.each(searchArr,function(ind,word){
    
    var resultWord = '';
    var engResultWord = '';
    if(text.toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1){
     resultWord = text.substring(text.toLowerCase().indexOf(word),text.toLowerCase().indexOf(word)+word.length);   
    }
    if(engText.toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1){
     engResultWord = engText.substring(engText.toLowerCase().indexOf(word),engText.toLowerCase().indexOf(word)+word.length);       
    }
    displayText = displayText.replace(resultWord,"<mark>" + resultWord + "</mark>").replace(/\r\n/g,"<br>");
    displayEngText = displayEngText.replace(engResultWord,"<mark>" + engResultWord + "</mark>").replace(/\r\n/g,"<br>");
   });
   
   // push the sentence to results
   if(i == 3){
    results.push([displayText,displayEngText,type,curObj['level1'],curObj['level2'],'',text,engText,curObj['eng1'],curObj['eng2'],'',"email" + (index + 1)]);   
   } else if (i == 2){
    results.push([displayText,displayEngText,type,curObj['level1'],'','',text,engText,curObj['eng1'],'','',"email" + (index + 1)]);
   } else {
    results.push([displayText,displayEngText,type,curObj['level1'],curObj['level2'],curObj['level3'],text,engText,curObj['eng1'],curObj['eng2'],curObj['eng3'],"email" + (index + 1)]);
   }
  }  
 }
}
```

the searchObj is a global array with some 1000 objects inside of it.

Could anyone explain to me why does this become gradually slower?

Thanks

Comment: Provide sample data (format) as well

Comment: can you add `console.log(searchObj.length); at the beginning of the function and see if it's not growing? Is there anything that changes between the 1st time you call the function and the last time when it's very slow? Are you searching for the same words?

Comment: @NurBar, try to reduce size of `searchObj` to , let's say, 50. And compare the execution time between two cases. Then tell what you have noticed

Comment: Can you provide a complete and operational jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you see the Timeline > Memory tab in Chrome's console and see if it's growing all the time?

Comment: It seems like your searchObj is growing, but your regex is crazy inefficient too.

Comment: This was great one, logging the number of objects was great, a bug kept isnerting new objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say anything for sure without actually testing your code with your data, but I can point out a thing or two that can probably improve performance.

You're using Regex completely wrong and your excessive use of `toLowerCase()` doesn't help either. You're Regex could have used the case-insensitive option (`i`) to ignore case, and the Regex `match` method could have been used to fetch the words from the text in it's original form, thus removing the need for both `toLowerCase()` and `substring()`, simplifying your function by much, IMO.

Right now I can't see the array of objects you're working with and your function doesn't return anything, so it isn't clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you provide a better example I'll be able to modify it and provide you with an example of what I suggest you do.

P.S. you can even use the Regex as part of a replace method if defined correctly, replacing all manual string manipulation with Regex.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips, I will be looking into it, the function ends up directing to other functions that create search results in the object, but that's not that important (it basically adds the results to a node).

The object was getting bigger from a bug somewhere else! but thanks for the help.